# Is it possible to use data binding library with the Preferences UI?

Tags: android, data-binding, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I want to use the data binding library with the Preferences/Settings Screen in my app.

If yes, please share a link to a tutorial or some other related content for the same.

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: were you able to find out a solution for this?